# Django - only admin account can login

Tags: django, backend

I created a function for users to log in to my website. However, it only works if I log in with an admin account, otherwise it cannot detect a registered user exist and said "This is user does not exist".

Here is the code:

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):

    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
        password = self.cleaned_data["password"]

        if username and password:
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if not user:
                raise forms.ValidationError("This is user does not exist")
            if not user.check_password(password):
                raise forms.ValidationError("Incorrect password")
            if not user.is_active:
                raise forms.ValidationError("This user is not longer active")
        return super(LoginForm, self).clean(*args, *kwargs)
```

Login view:

```
def login_view(request):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
    title = "Log in"
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('../../index/')

    return render(request, 'user/loginRegister.html', {'form': form, 'title': title})
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you show your view function as well?

Comment: @RajaSimon done

Comment: How did you create the registered user? Did you use `set_password` so that the password was hashed?

Comment: @Alasdair in the registerForm, I set password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput).   In register_view, I did 
 password = form.cleaned_data['password']
           user.set_password(password). It is hashed (cannnot directly see the password from databasae)

Comment: Is the `is_active` flag `True`?

Comment: The real problem rests with how you are registering the user. Could you post your user registration view as well?

Comment: @Alasdair Once I change the flag to true, it works! Does is_active means "this user is still been used these days" or "this user is now logged in, is active"? And can you repeat your answer in the answer part? I can accept it

Comment: Using admin interface check if the user you are trying to login is actually active.

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal it is solved, thank you!

Comment: @PiyushDas it is solved, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The default authentication backend will only log in users where [`is_active`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_active) is `True`.

By default, `is_active=True` means that the user is able to log in. It doesn't mean that they are currently logged in.